# Custom list definition + custom content type = showing only one form field?

Tags: sharepoint

Trying to use features to deploy custom fields, content type and list. So far I have a content type referencing custom and builtin fields. Content type inherits Item (0x01).

Now, I create custom list definition that references content type and fields (builtin and custom ones). I explicitly set `ShowInDisplayForm, ShowInEditForm, ShowInNewForm` values to true, however when I deploy feature and create list based on definition, all I get is only a single `Title` field in all forms!

However if I add field from UI to the list, it shows up in the form! Furthermore, if I create custom list from UI and add the content type, those fields are showing up in forms!

What's up with that?

By the way, I use VSeWSS tool for Visual Studio so it already genrates alot of stuff correctly.

Some code:

```
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01003420C661289843dbAB9E41F43C23BFD0" />
</ContentTypes>
<Fields>
  <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Group="$Resources:core,Extended_Columns" Required="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" Type="Text" Sortable="TRUE" Filterable="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
  <Field ID="{B4629012-C672-4911-B0D0-B9CB2DA44ED2}" DisplayName="Jautājumu pacēla" Group="$Resources:core,Extended_Columns" Name="QuestionRisedBy" Required="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" Type="User" Sortable="TRUE" Filterable="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
  <Field ID="{6DF9BD52-550E-4a30-BC31-A4366832A87F}" DisplayName="Komentārs" Group="$Resources:core,Extended_Columns" Name="Comment" AppendOnly="TRUE" Required="FALSE" NumLines="12" Type="Note" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" Filterable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
  <Field ID="{FC072586-E8BB-444f-AAA4-8D5745FBC096}" DisplayName="ParentItemId" Group="$Resources:core,Extended_Columns" Name="AgendaParentItemId" Required="TRUE" Type="Integer" Sortable="FALSE" Filterable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
  <Field ID="{29207E42-E107-4379-B620-BAAFC461276B}" DisplayName="AgendaRootItemId" Group="$Resources:core,Extended_Columns" Name="AgendaRootItemId" Required="TRUE" Type="Integer" Sortable="FALSE" Filterable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
  <Field ID="{06063FDB-3C2A-4141-91F7-28C2739CE6B5}" DisplayName="AgendaItemClosed" Group="$Resources:core,Extended_Columns" Name="AgendaItemClosed" Required="FALSE" Type="Boolean" Sortable="TRUE" Filterable="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
</Fields>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ContentType has FieldRefs for all the fields (Well, not inherited ones). However I read that when defining contet types in schema.xml, [you must explicitly define Field`s also](http://blogs.msdn.com/mcsnoiwb/archive/2008/12/01/creating-list-definitions-with-content-types.aspx) (that's weird), however **if you add ContentType programmatically, then it correctly adds CType fields to definition**.

By the way, what you see is what VSeWSS (microsoft extension for VS) tool generated (all the references).

[Quite from SharePoint blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mcsnoiwb/archive/2008/12/01/creating-list-definitions-with-content-types.aspx):

> What you need to do is to add the
>   exact same  elements to the
>    element as in the content
>   type, including the same ID. This is a
>   little strange, but in fact you need
>   to define the fields twice, both in
>   the content type and in the schema.xml
>   to make this work. You can skip the
>   Group and a few other properties.

However if I won't use Fields, I`ll get an exception:

```
[COMException (0x80004005): Nevar pabeigt šo darbību.

Lūdzu, mēģiniet vēlreiz.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetViewsSchemaXml(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bFullBlown, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plDefaultViewIndex) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetViewsSchemaXml(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bFullBlown, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plDefaultViewIndex) +122
```

Oh, well, anyway, I read somwhere an article (can't find that article no more)that suggest adding content type with feature receivers, then it properly shows up fields in forms.