# Hide inherited fields in new content types

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

I am trying to hide PercentComplete (% Complete) field in my custom content type that inherits from Workflow Task content type. And I am trying to do this with a feature. I am using the ID of PercentComplete field in FieldRefs element and setting ShowInDisplayForm to FALSE to no avail.

Do I have to use a feature receiver and do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set Hidden=TRUE in the FieldRef (see full reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225.aspx)
ShowInDisplayForm adds the percentage field, but hides it in (only) one of the forms.

Comment: Yes I tried every combination without success. I can hide the field from the Sharepoint UI but not from custom content type definition.

Comment: Hidden=TRUE works but as the name implies this hides the field everywhere, I just want to hide the field only on display forms.

Comment: Ok, seems like I didn't catch the question.
This one seems similar to your q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177831/custom-list-definition-custom-content-type-showing-only-one-form-field

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you are trying to do is possible.  I believe you can only set properties for the field on the list or @ the Site Collect (RootWeb) Fields list.